# Trocar texto utilizando a função ::before - CSS

Tags: html, css

Boa tarde amigos.

Estou tentando trocar um texto de uma pagina que só tenho acesso ao CSS.

Quero apenas trocar um termo.

Tentei com ::before e font-size:0; (na class pai do ::before), porém ai ficou tudo invisivel, inclusive o texto content do before.

Segue um pedacinho da gambiarra.

```
label.service::after {
  content: " de Transfer"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gabriel está dando errado pq o *pseudo-elemento* `::after` está herdadndo o `font-size` do pai que é 0, então vc tem que colocar um `font-size` pro `::after` ou então ele ficará 0 como o *pai* dele.

Veja como fica quando vc corrige isso colocando o `font-size` no *filho*. O texto do pai some, mas o do filho permanece.

**OBS:** repare que eu coloquei um `color` de texto no pai, e o texto do filho (`::after`) fica a mesma, então ele herda alguns atributos do pai, como foi o caso do `font-size`

```css
.service {
 font-size: 0;
    color:red; /* cor de texto que o filho ::after vai herdar */
}
.service::after {
  content: " de Transfer";
  font-size: 16px !important;
}
```

```html
<label for="" class="service">
  texto que some
</label>
```

---

**Tenha em mente que:** o usuário pode até não ver o texto que escondemos com `font-size: 0`, mas o Bot do Google com certeza vai ler esse conteúdo... Vai resolver pra que vê com os olhos, mas para os *crawlers* e leitores de tela o texto vai continuar acessível...

Comment: Bom dia amigo! vlw a dica, porém o "font-size" está retornando como "invalid property value". Até mesmo o "color" está como invalido. O que poderia ser?

Comment: @GabrielSalomão eu acabei de fazer o teste no validador de CSS da própria W3C e não acusou erro algum: http://www.css-validator.org/#validate_by_input e no Console do Chrome DevTools não aparece nada também, mas se vc usou a aba Audits pode sim ter dado algum aviso, pois lá eles avaliam a usabilidade e acessibilidade e font-size:0 vai contra isso, por isso fica a observação para vc ter em mente essa questão